# Adding data to a Chart after the page is loaded using php and chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

**Problem:** Well I´m trying to generate a chart using chart.js with information retrieved from a query. The controller retrieves the data and then I use the data in the function responsible for inserting new data in the chart `addData`. But this function is only called after the page is loaded, because the function `addData` is only available after the page is loaded. The main problem is that, the labels appear correct but data doesn´t appear in the chart.

When I use `console.log` on the `chart.data` and It shows the correct data that I´m trying to insert:

```
Objectdatasets: Array(1)0: {label: "Eventos", lineTension: 0.3, backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)", borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)", pointRadius: 3, …}data: (12) ["26", "26", "34", "22", "36", "39", "20", "6", "11", "13", "18", "250"]0: "26"1: "26"2: "34"3: "22"4: "36"5: "39"6: "20"7: "6"8: "11"9: "13"10: "18"11: "250"length: 12__proto__: Array(0)label: "Eventos"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)labels: (12) ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]0: "Jan"1: "Feb"2: "Mar"3: "Apr"4: "May"5: "Jun"6: "Jul"7: "Aug"8: "Sep"9: "Oct"10: "Nov"11: "Dec"length: 12__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

The controller that returns the information for the chart.

```
<?php
    function chart_area_eventos(){
            
            foreach(parent::get_chart_area_eventos() as $data){
    
                $values[] = $data->{'counter'};
                $labels[] = $data->{'month_name'};
            }
            $labels = json_encode($labels);
            $values = json_encode($values);
            ?>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load',function() {
        
            addData(myLineChart, <?php echo $labels.','.$values;?> , 'Eventos');
        });
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Where the chart is generated.

```
<div class="chart-area">
  <canvas id="myAreaChart"></canvas>
    <?php echo eventosController::chart_area_eventos();
</div>
```

JS Function responsible for adding the new values and new labels.

```
<script>
        function addData(chart, labels, data, label) {
            chart.data.labels = labels;
            chart.data.datasets.label = label;
            chart.data.datasets[0].label = label;
            chart.data.datasets.data = data;
        chart.update();
        chart.render();
        }
</script>
```